# Neo4j query set of nodes in set of labels and apply where clause for each type of node...dynamically

Tags: dynamic, neo4j, cypher

Ok, for starters this is a super long post so I apologize. I want to provide as much information on what I am doing as possible so we don't waste each others time.

Here goes. I am building a query up dynamically based on a set of filters (where clauses) users can create in the app. To give full background info...

The query starts off looking something like this:

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE labels(n) IN $labelsArray
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-(entity)
WHERE labels(entity) IN $labelsArray AND
r.endDate IS NULL
RETURN n, r
```

for example, if `$labelsArray` is `['User', 'Role']` then the query will be populated at run time like so:

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE labels(n) IN ['User', 'Role']
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-(entity)
WHERE labels(entity) IN ['User', 'Role'] AND
r.endDate IS NULL
RETURN n, r
```

This query will return all `User` nodes, all `Role`  nodes, and any relationship between the two (granted that the `endDate` on the relationship is `null`).

Ok, so that works fine. BUT, what if I want to start applying those filters (just a where clause) I was talking about. I am also building up filters dynamically (the user can create them through the app and I store the filter in the db).  I query the db to build up this filter and assuming it is the first filter, then in the end it looks like this:

```
AND
(
    labels(n) in ['User'] and
    n.firstName STARTS WITH 'B'
)
```

I store this value into a variable called `cypherWhere`.

When I inject this filter into the original query it looks like this:

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE labels(n) IN $labelsArray
$cypherWhere                                  <--- added this line
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-(entity)
WHERE labels(entity) IN $labelsArray AND
r.endDate IS NULL
RETURN n, r
```

Which at run time looks like this:

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE labels(n) IN ['User', 'Role']
AND
(
    labels(n) in ['User'] and
    n.firstName STARTS WITH 'B'
)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-(entity)
WHERE labels(entity) IN ['User', 'Role'] AND
r.endDate IS NULL
RETURN n, r
```

Ok, so far everything works just fine and dandy. I get all `User` nodes that have a `firstName` property that starts with `'B'`.

Now the issue I'm having is applying more than one filter. Say I have the following two filters:

```
AND
(
    labels(n) in ['User'] and
    n.firstName STARTS WITH 'B'
)
AND
(
    labels(n) in ['Role'] and
    n.displayName = 'Administrator'
)
```

which results in the run time query of:

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE labels(n) IN ['User', 'Role']
AND
(
    labels(n) in ['User'] and
    n.firstName STARTS WITH 'B'
)
AND
(
    labels(n) in ['Role'] and
    n.displayName = 'Administrator'
)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-(entity)
WHERE labels(entity) IN ['User', 'Role'] AND
r.endDate IS NULL
RETURN n, r
```

At this point I was about to get really excited and slap fives....but wait. I don't get any data back. I scored over the internet to see if there were any examples on how to do something similar to this and couldn't find anything.

I am under the assumption that the first where clause of

```
AND
(
    labels(n) in ['User'] and
    n.firstName STARTS WITH 'B'
)
```

immediately restricts my payload to users, and the second where clause that attempts to filter on `Role` nodes doesn't have any role nodes to filter on because the first query stripped out all nodes that weren't a `User`. I don't know if I am right but I think this is what is happening.

Ok, so back to the drawing board, how to I even write this simple query if I were to hard code it. I did and it looks like this:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE labels(n) IN ['Role']
AND n.displayName = 'Administrator'

MATCH (a)
WHERE labels(a) IN ['User']
AND a.firstName STARTS WITH 'B'

OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-(a)
where 
r.endDate IS NULL and a.endDate is null
RETURN n, a, r
```

And viola, this returns the data I was expecting. One problem though...How the heck am I supposed to build this thing up dynamically? I could have more than 2 nodes (3, 4, 5, etc) so aliasing them all is going to be tough. Plus I could have multiple filters on a particular node type. Say 2 filters on `User` nodes, and one filter on `Role` nodes, etc.

I'm a bit stuck now on how to build this up dynamically. The original path I was heading down leads to easily being able to build up dynamic cypher, but I don't know the correct syntax to lead me to do such a thing.

Can any body please provide some insight, even with some hard coded examples of how I can filter my `User` and `Role` nodes on the 2 where clause criteria. I am a beginner in cypher and am lacking the basic knowledge of how to syntactically do such a thing.

Comment: Looks to me like you're doing your label test backwards (`'User' in labels(n)` not `labels(n) in ['User']` -- you want to see if a certain string is in the list, not if a list is in a different list...) and you may just be incorrectly using `AND` where you need `OR` between your 2 conditions...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the labels comparison that I had backwards. I think you hit the nail on the head with using `OR` instead of `AND`. doh!  So it looks like I need to separate where clauses on different node types with an `OR`. But multiple where clauses on the same node type need to be separated with an `AND`.  This will lead to more complex cypher building on my end, but at least I have a direction to move towards. THANK YOU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the line `WHERE labels(n) IN ['User', 'Role']` is wrong (since you are testing if a list is into another list) and not necessary.
 So try build a query like:

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE
    (
        'User' IN labels(n)  and // fixed here...
        n.firstName STARTS WITH 'B'
    )
    OR // ... here
    (
        'Role' IN labels(n) and // ...and here.
        n.displayName = 'Administrator'
    )
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-(entity)
WHERE labels(entity) IN ['User', 'Role'] AND
r.endDate IS NULL
RETURN n, r
```

That is: remove the line `WHERE labels(n) IN ['User', 'Role']` and fix the tests using `labels(n)` function.

Also, since you are trying to get back all User nodes whos firstName starts with 'B' and also the Role nodes whos displayName is 'Administrator', you should use an `OR` instead of `AND` between the conditions.

Comment: What about the `WHERE labels(entity) IN ['User', 'Role'] AND` line. Is this comparison still fundamentally correct? I also assume you mean to have a `WHERE` on the second line?

Comment: Just tested this (added a `where` before the second line). You are correct in that the first `labels(n)` I was doing is not necessary. However, If there are no filters being applied then I do need that original comparison statement on the labels or else I get back every node in the db.  Also per @two-bit-alchemist comment, I needed an `OR` separating the 2 where clauses.

Comment: _However, If there are no filters being applied then I do need that original comparison statement on the labels or else I get back every node in the db._ What about store a "default filter" in the application and send it if no filter is passed by the user?

Comment: _Also per @two-bit-alchemist comment, I needed an OR separating the 2 where clauses._ Depends. If you put a `OR` separating the two conditions, you will get back all nodes that have **ONLY** `User` label OR **ONLY** `Role` label OR both (`User` and `Role` labels). I'm assuming you are trying to get back only user that have both User and Role labels.

Comment: Kind of, our nodes only have 1 label only at the moment. So I am trying to get back all `User` nodes whos `firstName` starts with 'B' and also the `Role` nodes whos `displayName` is 'Administrator'. You can see my confusion, because even in english I want to use the word `AND` when in reality I need an `OR` to get back the desired result set.  The default filter sounds like a good idea, I will ponder that one for sure.

Comment: @BradStell Oh right! :) So in this case you want an `OR`! I edited the answer to clarify it! Thanks!

Comment: @BradStell I would say in English you want the set of nodes which are Users (and) whose name starts with B, or which are Roles (and) whose display name is Administrator. Your phrasing issue comes from the fact that you're considering what you want in the results (this AND this) rather than how you match (it must have this AND that, OR that AND this). In any case, glad you got it sorted.